# Regression custom loss return value in Keras with and without custom loop

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

When a custom loss is defined in a Keras model, online sources seem to indicate that the the loss should return an array of values (a loss for each sample in the batch). Something like this

```
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
   squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
   return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss_function)
```

In the example above, I have no idea when or if the model is taking the batch sum or mean with  `tf.reduce_sum()` or `tf.reduce_mean()`

In another situation when we want to implement a custom training loop with a custom function, the template to follow according to Keras documentation is this

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_batch_pred = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  
            loss_value = custom_loss_function(y_batch_train, y_batch_pred)

        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

So by the book, if I understand correctly, we are supposed to take the mean of the batch gradients. Therefore, the loss value above should be a single value per batch.

However, the example will work with both of the following variations:

- `tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1) # array of loss for each sample`
- `tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference)          # mean loss for batch`

So, why does the first option (array loss) above still work? Is `apply_gradients` applying small changes for each value sequentially? Is this wrong although it works?

What is the correct way **without a custom loop**, and **with a custom loop**?

Comment: Which dimensions do y_batch_train and y_batch_pred have? Are the numpy arrays?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390725 ; Do the answers there help you?

Comment: @today it helped a little - definitely overlapping questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. In my opinion, this is not well documented in the TensorFlow/Keras API. By default, if you do not provide a scalar `loss_value`, TensorFlow will [add them up](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/AggregationMethod) (and the updates are not sequential). Essentially, this is equivalent to summing the losses along the batch axis.

Currently, the losses in the TensorFlow API include a `reduction` argument (for example, [tf.losses.MeanSquaredError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError)) that allows specifying how to aggregate the loss along the batch axis.